# Create a table of time series plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, timeserieschart

I'm trying to create a set of time series plot for different areas and want to place them into a table, which is exactly the same as what New York Times has done in their article [Coronavirus Map: Tracking the Global Outbreak](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/world/coronavirus-maps.html) (a snapshot of [Coronavirus case by country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1u58.png)).

The approach I originally came up with is to use heatmaps where each row represents an area and each column represents a time stamp. But the output won't look as nice as NYTime's example. I'm wondering if anyone could give me a hint for improvement.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Maybe can you can provide the code that you have try and the corresponding output.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of you can use `geom_tile` to get a "similar" graph:

Starting with this fake example:

```r
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(USA = c(rep(1,5),5,10,25,50,150,200,250,250,250),
                 Italy = c(rep(1,2),5,10,25,50,100,150,175,200,250,300,350,400),
                 Date = seq(ymd("2020-01-01"),ymd("2020-04-01"), by = "1 weeks"))
```

You can reshape the dataframe into a longer format using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and plot values as follow in `ggplot2`. You can pay with width and height argument of `geom_tile` to get close to the original graph.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "country", values_to = "Cases") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = country, fill = Cases))+
  geom_tile(width = 5, height = 0.5, color = "black")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "week", date_labels = "%b %d")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thank you so much, I was playing with the parameters of `geom_tile` and got something similar. I was wondering if it's possible to combine text and plot element and create a table like in the NYT article. Is it something that is more suitable with other visualization tools instead of ggplot?

Comment: Maybe you can try to take a look at `formattable` package that allow to make nice tables. Not sure how to combine the heatmap part into this.